# Is the completion of an XDomainRequest in IE9 sensitive to other javascript activity

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a page that makes a cross site request to another application to gather some details.

One page in the app succeeds in making this GET request.  This page, by and large, just displays the details that come from that request.

Another page in the app fails to make the GET request (the browser aborts the request).  This page displays the same details as the first page, but also has several additional UI elements.

The pages are from the same app, they have the same domain and protocol.  The only thing different is the path of the page.

Specifically, I have:

Working Page: https://outreach.example.com/members/32234254
Failing Page: https://outreach.example.com/cases/9975

Both pages are making a request to:

https://crucible.example.com/api/members/234ABE2342349.json?token=valid_token

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is being returned with the value: https://outreach.example.com

The AJAX requests are identical and Fiddler clearly shows both succeeding; but IE aborts the request coming from the failing page.

In both cases, the pages have a client side UI generated by knockout.js.  The biggest difference is that the page that succeeds doesn't start rendering until the request returns, while the page that fails is rendering while the request is pending.

Is the XDR sensitive to other DOM or javascript activity in the browser?  The best discussion of XDR that I have found is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx/%20here), but it doesn't mention anything about this.  There's also nothing about this in the [XDR documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx%20).

Are there steps that I can take to ensure that my requests are not aborted by the browser?

Comment: The browser's decision to make/abort the request should not be based on other DOM or JavaScript activity. Make sure your CORS headers are right. Are the two pages on different domains/subdomains?

Comment: @JoshuaDwire I updated the question to answer your questions: the pages differ only by path, and the CORS header is correct.